# Must a T-Sql stored procedure contain script to support a SqlClient transaction?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that deletes rows.  Sample code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ap_um_delete_tems_grid]
(
    @agency char(3) 
    , @subagency char(1)
    , @grid_id int
    , @role_id int
)
AS
DELETE FROM [grid_setup]
  WHERE agency = @agency 
    AND subagency = @subagency 
    AND gs.grid_id = @grid_id 
    AND role_id = @role_id
```

If I execute this SProc directly from Sql Mgmt Studio it works fine.  However, if I attempt to do it in C# code using a transaction, I get a very interesting SqlException:

> Incorrect syntax near 'ap_um_delete_tems_grid'

The exception detail says it occurs on line number 1.  The C# code is:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn.TemsConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SqlTransaction transaction;

    // Start the local transaction
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("GridReplaceTransaction");
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    try
    {
        command.CommandText = "ap_um_delete_tems_grid";

        SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter();

        // Adding the parameters

        int cnt = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

The code above worked before I put it into a transaction.  Why am I getting the syntax error?  Perhaps because there needs to be something in the SProc to support the transaction?  Or am I messsing something else up?

NOTE: *Please don't try to tell me I don't need a transaction for a single delete.  The above is part of a multi-step process, namely adding new rows after the delete. Thanks.*

Comment: Sorry, wanted it to stand out before someone told me something that doesn't matter to the question.  Not shouting, just wanted to stop someone from making a useless comment.  I've seen this kind of thing before, just wanted to short-circuit it.

Comment: Toned down the note by replacing uppercase with italics.  Don't want to seem overbearing or freaked out.

Comment: You have several other _newb_ mistakes: your `SqlCommand` and `SqlTransaction` need to be in `using` blocks. Also, it's a very bad idea to ignore exceptions. You should rethrow it with `throw;` or throw a new exception with `ex` as the `InnerException`: `throw new Exception("My message", ex);`. At worst, you should log or display the full `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing:

```
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Otherwise, it uses the default of  `CommandType.Text` and treats `"ap_um_delete_tems_grid"` as a statement rather than the name of a stored procedure.

Comment: O.M.G.  I can't believe I made such a simple *noob* mistake.  Of course you're completely correct; once I added this line it worked perfectly.